# Heap size boundries

Tags: heap-memory

I am solving problems of euler using java for fun for a few months now. Many times the heap size limits me, so I wondered what others do when they reach this dead and fraustrating end.

A good example is of the problem "http://projecteuler.net/problem=432" where I have a neat function that solves for 10^6 in few milisec, but I can't apply it to the requested value (10^11) because it requires an integer array in size 10^11.

EDIT: To clarify the question. Is there any way of sieving for big numbers? How what would you if, for example, you had to find the first prime bigger than 10^10?

Answer (score 0):

If your solution requires an array of 10**11 integers, then you need to buy a computer with at least 745GB of memory. It seems reasonable that the default heap size isn't that large. Or you need to rethink it and not use such a huge array.

Comment: Yeah, obvisouly I never intentionaly implied I expect the array to be this big, just maybe if there are other data stractures you know of or such. What is usualy your approach when you reach such dead end?

Comment: @user2435678: I rethink the algorithm. Do you need the values more than once? If not, they don't need to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

For the really big prime numbers, you cannot get from sieve of eratosthenes because the sieve array's max length is restricted by Integer.MAX_VALUE.

You can calculate them by the most straightforward method -

prime(N) = if every prime in [0, sqrt(N)] is not a prime factor of N.

And store all the big primes you calculated in a file or several files. Do it once, then reuse them. Load these primes from file to memory first when you are doing an euler problem which needs big primes.